# Jelastic run.log not working on docker

Tags: logging, docker, jelastic

i'm deploying some docker containers in Jelastic cloud but the `run.log` file from the log menu item in the container node shows nothing for some containers and sometimes says `The operation could not be performed`, is there something i need to do so the logs appear?

Currently the docker images prints logs to stdout, and work in anyplace, except there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that your Docker image doesn't have a grep utility inside:

```
node46581-env-5967225:/# grep error -i /var/log/run.log 
-bash: grep: command not found
```

But this utility is required to output logs to GUI, so after the installation...

```
node46581-env-5967225:/# apk add grep
(1/2) Installing pcre (8.38-r1)
(2/2) Installing grep (2.25-r0)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r11.trigger
OK: 105 MiB in 35 packages
```

... logs have appeared:

[image]

Thus, in order to get rid of this issue, you have to consider an installation of grep in your repository.

Best regards, Jelastic Team.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Didnt know that i need grep, I'll install in all mext images